# Connecting two functions in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I'm trying to draw two horizontal lines, y = 0 and y = 1, in [0, 1], in front of the already existing plot. The intended result is:

[image]

The current result is:

[image]

Obtained from:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
           \begin{axis} [xlabel = $E/U_0$]
               \addplot [blue] table [x index = 0, y index = 1] {data/step_potential.txt};
               \addplot [red] table [x index = 0, y index = 2] {data/step_potential.txt};

               \addlegendentry{$T$};        
               \addlegendentry{$R$};    
           \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

```
step_potential.txt

 1.0000000000000000e+000 0.0000000000000000e+000 1.0000000000000000e+000
 1.0100000000000000e+000 3.2923492534173249e-001 6.7076507465826785e-001
 1.0200000000000000e+000 4.3096684525476525e-001 5.6903315474523464e-001
 1.0300000000000000e+000 4.9812398324487062e-001 5.0187601675512927e-001
 1.0400000000000000e+000 5.4831057194883326e-001 4.5168942805116669e-001
 1.0500000000000000e+000 5.8816665289028502e-001 4.1183334710971514e-001
 1.0600000000000001e+000 6.2101301107749707e-001 3.7898698892250299e-001
 1.0700000000000001e+000 6.4877461512644574e-001 3.5122538487355437e-001
 1.0800000000000001e+000 6.7267588878167384e-001 3.2732411121832633e-001
 1.0900000000000001e+000 6.9354740166173390e-001 3.0645259833826582e-001
 1.1000000000000001e+000 7.1197989937059203e-001 2.8802010062940792e-001
 1.1100000000000001e+000 7.2840914846244020e-001 2.7159085153755980e-001
 1.1200000000000001e+000 7.4316603575847751e-001 2.5683396424152261e-001
 1.1299999999999999e+000 7.5650780399106932e-001 2.4349219600893063e-001
 1.1400000000000001e+000 7.6863839799686962e-001 2.3136160200313030e-001
 1.1499999999999999e+000 7.7972220435869932e-001 2.2027779564130059e-001
 1.1599999999999999e+000 7.8989361453361440e-001 2.1010638546638555e-001
 1.1699999999999999e+000 7.9926385456881544e-001 2.0073614543118440e-001
 1.1799999999999999e+000 8.0792597210431361e-001 1.9207402789568637e-001
 1.1899999999999999e+000 8.1595854889549779e-001 1.8404145110450210e-001
 1.2000000000000000e+000 8.2342851191715916e-001 1.7657148808284054e-001
 1.2100000000000000e+000 8.3039329420840891e-001 1.6960670579159123e-001
 1.2200000000000000e+000 8.3690251834617779e-001 1.6309748165382229e-001
 1.2300000000000000e+000 8.4299932393270594e-001 1.5700067606729398e-001
 1.2400000000000000e+000 8.4872142584625077e-001 1.5127857415374935e-001
 1.2500000000000000e+000 8.5410196624968437e-001 1.4589803375031546e-001
 1.2600000000000000e+000 8.5917020676901745e-001 1.4082979323098221e-001
 1.2700000000000000e+000 8.6395209549029139e-001 1.3604790450970863e-001
 1.2800000000000000e+000 8.6847073495510296e-001 1.3152926504489690e-001
 1.2900000000000000e+000 8.7274677115670163e-001 1.2725322884329854e-001
 1.3000000000000000e+000 8.7679871897497508e-001 1.2320128102502519e-001
 1.3100000000000001e+000 8.8064323607916906e-001 1.1935676392083092e-001
 1.3200000000000001e+000 8.8429535475295185e-001 1.1570464524704797e-001
 1.3300000000000001e+000 8.8776867913378055e-001 1.1223132086621918e-001
 1.3400000000000001e+000 8.9107555384845194e-001 1.0892444615154812e-001
 1.3500000000000001e+000 8.9422720885495688e-001 1.0577279114504318e-001
 1.3599999999999999e+000 8.9723388438427987e-001 1.0276611561571992e-001
 1.3700000000000001e+000 9.0010493915359346e-001 9.9895060846406356e-002
 1.3799999999999999e+000 9.0284894444923902e-001 9.7151055550761034e-002
 1.3900000000000001e+000 9.0547376622015041e-001 9.4526233779849575e-002
 1.3999999999999999e+000 9.0798663695447557e-001 9.2013363045524446e-002
 1.4100000000000001e+000 9.1039421881472926e-001 8.9605781185270766e-002
 1.4199999999999999e+000 9.1270265926502314e-001 8.7297340734977039e-002
 1.4299999999999999e+000 9.1491764022632649e-001 8.5082359773673566e-002
 1.4399999999999999e+000 9.1704442163342570e-001 8.2955578366574384e-002
 1.4500000000000000e+000 9.1908788013333487e-001 8.0912119866665411e-002
 1.4600000000000000e+000 9.2105254355390809e-001 7.8947456446091802e-002
 1.4700000000000000e+000 9.2294262167899677e-001 7.7057378321003386e-002
 1.4800000000000000e+000 9.2476203378923783e-001 7.5237966210762189e-002
 1.4900000000000000e+000 9.2651443336276518e-001 7.3485566637235086e-002
 1.5000000000000000e+000 9.2820323027550911e-001 7.1796769724490811e-002
 1.5100000000000000e+000 9.2983161079462662e-001 7.0168389205373466e-002
 1.5200000000000000e+000 9.3140255561943253e-001 6.8597444380567571e-002
 1.5300000000000000e+000 9.3291885619091686e-001 6.7081143809083185e-002
 1.5400000000000000e+000 9.3438312946247548e-001 6.5616870537524699e-002
 1.5500000000000000e+000 9.3579783130014305e-001 6.4202168699857079e-002
 1.5600000000000001e+000 9.3716526865971095e-001 6.2834731340289302e-002
 1.5700000000000001e+000 9.3848761067009812e-001 6.1512389329902044e-002
 1.5800000000000001e+000 9.3976689873680952e-001 6.0233101263190238e-002
 1.5899999999999999e+000 9.4100505576585036e-001 5.8994944234149568e-002
 1.6000000000000001e+000 9.4220389459678688e-001 5.7796105403213054e-002
 1.6099999999999999e+000 9.4336512572349407e-001 5.6634874276505945e-002
 1.6200000000000001e+000 9.4449036437225942e-001 5.5509635627740639e-002
 1.6299999999999999e+000 9.4558113699918056e-001 5.4418863000819440e-002
 1.6400000000000001e+000 9.4663888726201262e-001 5.3361112737987167e-002
 1.6499999999999999e+000 9.4766498151567025e-001 5.2335018484329615e-002
 1.6600000000000001e+000 9.4866071387535911e-001 5.1339286124640920e-002
 1.6699999999999999e+000 9.4962731088670160e-001 5.0372689113298168e-002
 1.6800000000000002e+000 9.5056593583815474e-001 4.9434064161844982e-002
 1.6899999999999999e+000 9.5147769274740956e-001 4.8522307252590546e-002
 1.7000000000000002e+000 9.5236363005028601e-001 4.7636369949714139e-002
 1.7100000000000000e+000 9.5322474401780088e-001 4.6775255982198886e-002
 1.7200000000000000e+000 9.5406198192456848e-001 4.5938018075431776e-002
 1.7300000000000000e+000 9.5487624498945123e-001 4.5123755010548834e-002
 1.7400000000000000e+000 9.5566839110739921e-001 4.4331608892600828e-002
 1.7500000000000000e+000 9.5643923738959991e-001 4.3560762610399990e-002
 1.7600000000000000e+000 9.5718956252749443e-001 4.2810437472505618e-002
 1.7700000000000000e+000 9.5792010899476576e-001 4.2079891005234391e-002
 1.7800000000000000e+000 9.5863158510013347e-001 4.1368414899866500e-002
 1.7900000000000000e+000 9.5932466690263041e-001 4.0675333097369468e-002
 1.8000000000000000e+000 9.6000000000000019e-001 3.9999999999999994e-002
 1.8100000000000001e+000 9.6065820119992340e-001 3.9341798800076440e-002
 1.8200000000000001e+000 9.6129986008294188e-001 3.8700139917058236e-002
 1.8300000000000001e+000 9.6192554046517187e-001 3.8074459534828367e-002
 1.8399999999999999e+000 9.6253578176823773e-001 3.7464218231762443e-002
 1.8500000000000001e+000 9.6313110030320837e-001 3.6868899696791316e-002
 1.8599999999999999e+000 9.6371199047477285e-001 3.6288009525226955e-002
 1.8700000000000001e+000 9.6427892591136599e-001 3.5721074088633946e-002
 1.8799999999999999e+000 9.6483236052650689e-001 3.5167639473493086e-002
 1.8900000000000001e+000 9.6537272951617370e-001 3.4627270483826279e-002
 1.8999999999999999e+000 9.6590045029666316e-001 3.4099549703336847e-002
 1.9100000000000001e+000 9.6641592338703142e-001 3.3584076612968486e-002
 1.9199999999999999e+000 9.6691953323989288e-001 3.3080466760107140e-002
 1.9300000000000002e+000 9.6741164902405941e-001 3.2588350975940525e-002
 1.9399999999999999e+000 9.6789262536224308e-001 3.2107374637756883e-002
 1.9500000000000002e+000 9.6836280302679123e-001 3.1637196973208645e-002
 1.9600000000000000e+000 9.6882250959621130e-001 3.1177490403788699e-002
 1.9700000000000000e+000 9.6927206007502731e-001 3.0727939924972785e-002
 1.9800000000000000e+000 9.6971175747933225e-001 3.0288242520667634e-002
 1.9900000000000000e+000 9.7014189339022228e-001 2.9858106609777578e-002
 2.0000000000000000e+000 9.7056274847714075e-001 2.9437251522859406e-002
 2.0099999999999998e+000 9.7097459299301891e-001 2.9025407006981151e-002
 2.0200000000000000e+000 9.7137768724296569e-001 2.8622312757034214e-002
 2.0300000000000002e+000 9.7177228202812926e-001 2.8227717971870896e-002
 2.0400000000000000e+000 9.7215861906624745e-001 2.7841380933752619e-002
 2.0499999999999998e+000 9.7253693139030017e-001 2.7463068609699801e-002
 2.0600000000000001e+000 9.7290744372657045e-001 2.7092556273429484e-002
 2.0700000000000003e+000 9.7327037285334328e-001 2.6729627146656873e-002
 2.0800000000000001e+000 9.7362592794138070e-001 2.6374072058619209e-002
 2.0899999999999999e+000 9.7397431087724418e-001 2.6025689122755900e-002
 2.1000000000000001e+000 9.7431571657044924e-001 2.5684283429550554e-002
 2.1100000000000003e+000 9.7465033324539518e-001 2.5349666754604816e-002
 2.1200000000000001e+000 9.7497834271892503e-001 2.5021657281074725e-002
 2.1299999999999999e+000 9.7529992066434334e-001 2.4700079335656738e-002
 2.1400000000000001e+000 9.7561523686263774e-001 2.4384763137362177e-002
 2.1500000000000004e+000 9.7592445544163176e-001 2.4075544558368172e-002
 2.1600000000000001e+000 9.7622773510372407e-001 2.3772264896276020e-002
 2.1699999999999999e+000 9.7652522934284780e-001 2.3474770657152248e-002
 2.1799999999999997e+000 9.7681708665123512e-001 2.3182913348764919e-002
 2.1899999999999999e+000 9.7710345071653604e-001 2.2896549283463852e-002
 2.2000000000000002e+000 9.7738446060981210e-001 2.2615539390187827e-002
 2.2100000000000000e+000 9.7766025096488718e-001 2.2339749035112880e-002
 2.2199999999999998e+000 9.7793095214951498e-001 2.2069047850485014e-002
 2.2300000000000000e+000 9.7819669042879254e-001 2.1803309571207529e-002
 2.2400000000000002e+000 9.7845758812121986e-001 2.1542411878780129e-002
 2.2500000000000000e+000 9.7871376374779184e-001 2.1286236252208168e-002
 2.2599999999999998e+000 9.7896533217447401e-001 2.1034667825525849e-002
 2.2700000000000000e+000 9.7921240474840532e-001 2.0787595251594650e-002
 2.2800000000000002e+000 9.7945508942813952e-001 2.0544910571860531e-002
 2.2900000000000000e+000 9.7969349090823021e-001 2.0306509091769800e-002
 2.2999999999999998e+000 9.7992771073843910e-001 2.0072289261561006e-002
 2.3100000000000001e+000 9.8015784743783319e-001 1.9842152562166804e-002
 2.3200000000000003e+000 9.8038399660402631e-001 1.9616003395973816e-002
 2.3300000000000001e+000 9.8060625101779697e-001 1.9393748982202936e-002
 2.3399999999999999e+000 9.8082470074331440e-001 1.9175299256685558e-002
 2.3500000000000001e+000 9.8103943322417630e-001 1.8960566775823733e-002
 2.3600000000000003e+000 9.8125053337546664e-001 1.8749466624533376e-002
 2.3700000000000001e+000 9.8145808367201903e-001 1.8541916327981144e-002
 2.3799999999999999e+000 9.8166216423306485e-001 1.8337835766935082e-002
 2.3900000000000001e+000 9.8186285290344055e-001 1.8137147096559478e-002
 2.4000000000000004e+000 9.8206022533150705e-001 1.7939774668492756e-002
 2.4100000000000001e+000 9.8225435504394387e-001 1.7745644956056211e-002
 2.4199999999999999e+000 9.8244531351755093e-001 1.7554686482448935e-002
 2.4299999999999997e+000 9.8263317024820784e-001 1.7366829751792216e-002
 2.4399999999999999e+000 9.8281799281710636e-001 1.7182007182893717e-002
 2.4500000000000002e+000 9.8299984695439213e-001 1.7000153045607983e-002
 2.4600000000000000e+000 9.8317879660032348e-001 1.6821203399676670e-002
 2.4699999999999998e+000 9.8335490396406244e-001 1.6645096035937553e-002
 2.4800000000000000e+000 9.8352822958020303e-001 1.6471770419797045e-002
 2.4900000000000002e+000 9.8369883236313393e-001 1.6301167636866145e-002
 2.5000000000000000e+000 9.8386676965933506e-001 1.6133230340664932e-002
 2.5099999999999998e+000 9.8403209729769492e-001 1.5967902702305026e-002
 2.5200000000000000e+000 9.8419486963793534e-001 1.5805130362064556e-002
 2.5300000000000002e+000 9.8435513961722654e-001 1.5644860382773552e-002
 2.5400000000000000e+000 9.8451295879506762e-001 1.5487041204932404e-002
 2.5499999999999998e+000 9.8466837739651070e-001 1.5331622603489520e-002
 2.5600000000000001e+000 9.8482144435379271e-001 1.5178555646207220e-002
 2.5700000000000003e+000 9.8497220734645030e-001 1.5027792653549926e-002
 2.5800000000000001e+000 9.8512071283996994e-001 1.4879287160029836e-002
 2.5899999999999999e+000 9.8526700612305040e-001 1.4732993876949915e-002
 2.6000000000000001e+000 9.8541113134351410e-001 1.4588868656485954e-002
 2.6100000000000003e+000 9.8555313154294699e-001 1.4446868457052868e-002
 2.6200000000000001e+000 9.8569304869009788e-001 1.4306951309902158e-002
 2.6299999999999999e+000 9.8583092371309955e-001 1.4169076286900549e-002
 2.6400000000000001e+000 9.8596679653055785e-001 1.4033203469441889e-002
 2.6500000000000004e+000 9.8610070608155342e-001 1.3899293918446800e-002
 2.6600000000000001e+000 9.8623269035459404e-001 1.3767309645405793e-002
 2.6699999999999999e+000 9.8636278641557495e-001 1.3637213584425201e-002
 2.6799999999999997e+000 9.8649103043476449e-001 1.3508969565235264e-002
 2.6899999999999999e+000 9.8661745771287723e-001 1.3382542287122769e-002
 2.7000000000000002e+000 9.8674210270624763e-001 1.3257897293752006e-002
 2.7100000000000000e+000 9.8686499905116076e-001 1.3135000948839140e-002
 2.7199999999999998e+000 9.8698617958735291e-001 1.3013820412646924e-002
 2.7300000000000000e+000 9.8710567638073177e-001 1.2894323619268120e-002
 2.7400000000000002e+000 9.8722352074533293e-001 1.2776479254667052e-002
 2.7500000000000000e+000 9.8733974326454921e-001 1.2660256735450733e-002
 2.7599999999999998e+000 9.8745437381165868e-001 1.2545626188341158e-002
 2.7700000000000000e+000 9.8756744156967713e-001 1.2432558430322852e-002
 2.7800000000000002e+000 9.8767897505056035e-001 1.2321024949439780e-002
 2.7900000000000000e+000 9.8778900211378229e-001 1.2210997886217517e-002
 2.7999999999999998e+000 9.8789754998431289e-001 1.2102450015687103e-002
 2.8100000000000001e+000 9.8800464527001153e-001 1.1995354729988609e-002
 2.8200000000000003e+000 9.8811031397846727e-001 1.1889686021532614e-002
 2.8300000000000001e+000 9.8821458153330077e-001 1.1785418466699435e-002
 2.8399999999999999e+000 9.8831747278994397e-001 1.1682527210056040e-002
 2.8500000000000001e+000 9.8841901205092797e-001 1.1580987949072214e-002
 2.8600000000000003e+000 9.8851922308068252e-001 1.1480776919317662e-002
 2.8700000000000001e+000 9.8861812911987734e-001 1.1381870880122671e-002
 2.8799999999999999e+000 9.8871575289931424e-001 1.1284247100685877e-002
 2.8900000000000001e+000 9.8881211665338697e-001 1.1187883346612935e-002
 2.9000000000000004e+000 9.8890724213312897e-001 1.1092757866871042e-002
 2.9100000000000001e+000 9.8900115061885563e-001 1.0998849381144411e-002
 2.9199999999999999e+000 9.8909386293242341e-001 1.0906137067576616e-002
 2.9299999999999997e+000 9.8918539944911388e-001 1.0814600550886217e-002
 2.9399999999999999e+000 9.8927578010915718e-001 1.0724219890842865e-002
 2.9500000000000002e+000 9.8936502442890895e-001 1.0634975571090985e-002
 2.9600000000000000e+000 9.8945315151169055e-001 1.0546848488309423e-002
 2.9699999999999998e+000 9.8954018005830502e-001 1.0459819941695108e-002
 2.9800000000000000e+000 9.8962612837724018e-001 1.0373871622759956e-002
 2.9900000000000002e+000 9.8971101439456965e-001 1.0288985605430241e-002
 3.0000000000000000e+000 9.8979485566356196e-001 1.0205144336438028e-002
```

Comment: As always on this site please provide a full minimal example that others can just copy and try as is. Here there is no documentclass, the data is missing, so hardly anyone can test your code. Plus not everyone knows this is a `pgfplots` question, so perhaps add that tag.

Comment: Just add a line to the beginning of your `step_potential.txt`, with `0 0 1`. Also, for questions that include an external data file, you can embed the data in the MWE with the [`filecontents`](http://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/filecontents/filecontents.pdf) package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

or like this:

[image]

in the first case the mwe is:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{filecontents}% <---

\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
1.0000000000000000e+000 0.0000000000000000e+000 1.0000000000000000e+000
 1.0100000000000000e+000 3.2923492534173249e-001 6.7076507465826785e-001
 1.0200000000000000e+000 4.3096684525476525e-001 5.6903315474523464e-001
 1.0300000000000000e+000 4.9812398324487062e-001 5.0187601675512927e-001
 1.0400000000000000e+000 5.4831057194883326e-001 4.5168942805116669e-001
 1.0500000000000000e+000 5.8816665289028502e-001 4.1183334710971514e-001
 1.0600000000000001e+000 6.2101301107749707e-001 3.7898698892250299e-001
 1.0700000000000001e+000 6.4877461512644574e-001 3.5122538487355437e-001
 1.0800000000000001e+000 6.7267588878167384e-001 3.2732411121832633e-001
 1.0900000000000001e+000 6.9354740166173390e-001 3.0645259833826582e-001
 1.1000000000000001e+000 7.1197989937059203e-001 2.8802010062940792e-001
 1.1100000000000001e+000 7.2840914846244020e-001 2.7159085153755980e-001
 1.1200000000000001e+000 7.4316603575847751e-001 2.5683396424152261e-001
 1.1299999999999999e+000 7.5650780399106932e-001 2.4349219600893063e-001
 1.1400000000000001e+000 7.6863839799686962e-001 2.3136160200313030e-001
 1.1499999999999999e+000 7.7972220435869932e-001 2.2027779564130059e-001
 1.1599999999999999e+000 7.8989361453361440e-001 2.1010638546638555e-001
 1.1699999999999999e+000 7.9926385456881544e-001 2.0073614543118440e-001
 1.1799999999999999e+000 8.0792597210431361e-001 1.9207402789568637e-001
 1.1899999999999999e+000 8.1595854889549779e-001 1.8404145110450210e-001
 1.2000000000000000e+000 8.2342851191715916e-001 1.7657148808284054e-001
 1.2100000000000000e+000 8.3039329420840891e-001 1.6960670579159123e-001
 1.2200000000000000e+000 8.3690251834617779e-001 1.6309748165382229e-001
 1.2300000000000000e+000 8.4299932393270594e-001 1.5700067606729398e-001
 1.2400000000000000e+000 8.4872142584625077e-001 1.5127857415374935e-001
 1.2500000000000000e+000 8.5410196624968437e-001 1.4589803375031546e-001
 1.2600000000000000e+000 8.5917020676901745e-001 1.4082979323098221e-001
 1.2700000000000000e+000 8.6395209549029139e-001 1.3604790450970863e-001
 1.2800000000000000e+000 8.6847073495510296e-001 1.3152926504489690e-001
 1.2900000000000000e+000 8.7274677115670163e-001 1.2725322884329854e-001
 1.3000000000000000e+000 8.7679871897497508e-001 1.2320128102502519e-001
 1.3100000000000001e+000 8.8064323607916906e-001 1.1935676392083092e-001
 1.3200000000000001e+000 8.8429535475295185e-001 1.1570464524704797e-001
 1.3300000000000001e+000 8.8776867913378055e-001 1.1223132086621918e-001
 1.3400000000000001e+000 8.9107555384845194e-001 1.0892444615154812e-001
 1.3500000000000001e+000 8.9422720885495688e-001 1.0577279114504318e-001
 1.3599999999999999e+000 8.9723388438427987e-001 1.0276611561571992e-001
 1.3700000000000001e+000 9.0010493915359346e-001 9.9895060846406356e-002
 1.3799999999999999e+000 9.0284894444923902e-001 9.7151055550761034e-002
 1.3900000000000001e+000 9.0547376622015041e-001 9.4526233779849575e-002
 1.3999999999999999e+000 9.0798663695447557e-001 9.2013363045524446e-002
 1.4100000000000001e+000 9.1039421881472926e-001 8.9605781185270766e-002
 1.4199999999999999e+000 9.1270265926502314e-001 8.7297340734977039e-002
 1.4299999999999999e+000 9.1491764022632649e-001 8.5082359773673566e-002
 1.4399999999999999e+000 9.1704442163342570e-001 8.2955578366574384e-002
 1.4500000000000000e+000 9.1908788013333487e-001 8.0912119866665411e-002
 1.4600000000000000e+000 9.2105254355390809e-001 7.8947456446091802e-002
 1.4700000000000000e+000 9.2294262167899677e-001 7.7057378321003386e-002
 1.4800000000000000e+000 9.2476203378923783e-001 7.5237966210762189e-002
 1.4900000000000000e+000 9.2651443336276518e-001 7.3485566637235086e-002
 1.5000000000000000e+000 9.2820323027550911e-001 7.1796769724490811e-002
 1.5100000000000000e+000 9.2983161079462662e-001 7.0168389205373466e-002
 1.5200000000000000e+000 9.3140255561943253e-001 6.8597444380567571e-002
 1.5300000000000000e+000 9.3291885619091686e-001 6.7081143809083185e-002
 1.5400000000000000e+000 9.3438312946247548e-001 6.5616870537524699e-002
 1.5500000000000000e+000 9.3579783130014305e-001 6.4202168699857079e-002
 1.5600000000000001e+000 9.3716526865971095e-001 6.2834731340289302e-002
 1.5700000000000001e+000 9.3848761067009812e-001 6.1512389329902044e-002
 1.5800000000000001e+000 9.3976689873680952e-001 6.0233101263190238e-002
 1.5899999999999999e+000 9.4100505576585036e-001 5.8994944234149568e-002
 1.6000000000000001e+000 9.4220389459678688e-001 5.7796105403213054e-002
 1.6099999999999999e+000 9.4336512572349407e-001 5.6634874276505945e-002
 1.6200000000000001e+000 9.4449036437225942e-001 5.5509635627740639e-002
 1.6299999999999999e+000 9.4558113699918056e-001 5.4418863000819440e-002
 1.6400000000000001e+000 9.4663888726201262e-001 5.3361112737987167e-002
 1.6499999999999999e+000 9.4766498151567025e-001 5.2335018484329615e-002
 1.6600000000000001e+000 9.4866071387535911e-001 5.1339286124640920e-002
 1.6699999999999999e+000 9.4962731088670160e-001 5.0372689113298168e-002
 1.6800000000000002e+000 9.5056593583815474e-001 4.9434064161844982e-002
 1.6899999999999999e+000 9.5147769274740956e-001 4.8522307252590546e-002
 1.7000000000000002e+000 9.5236363005028601e-001 4.7636369949714139e-002
 1.7100000000000000e+000 9.5322474401780088e-001 4.6775255982198886e-002
 1.7200000000000000e+000 9.5406198192456848e-001 4.5938018075431776e-002
 1.7300000000000000e+000 9.5487624498945123e-001 4.5123755010548834e-002
 1.7400000000000000e+000 9.5566839110739921e-001 4.4331608892600828e-002
 1.7500000000000000e+000 9.5643923738959991e-001 4.3560762610399990e-002
 1.7600000000000000e+000 9.5718956252749443e-001 4.2810437472505618e-002
 1.7700000000000000e+000 9.5792010899476576e-001 4.2079891005234391e-002
 1.7800000000000000e+000 9.5863158510013347e-001 4.1368414899866500e-002
 1.7900000000000000e+000 9.5932466690263041e-001 4.0675333097369468e-002
 1.8000000000000000e+000 9.6000000000000019e-001 3.9999999999999994e-002
 1.8100000000000001e+000 9.6065820119992340e-001 3.9341798800076440e-002
 1.8200000000000001e+000 9.6129986008294188e-001 3.8700139917058236e-002
 1.8300000000000001e+000 9.6192554046517187e-001 3.8074459534828367e-002
 1.8399999999999999e+000 9.6253578176823773e-001 3.7464218231762443e-002
 1.8500000000000001e+000 9.6313110030320837e-001 3.6868899696791316e-002
 1.8599999999999999e+000 9.6371199047477285e-001 3.6288009525226955e-002
 1.8700000000000001e+000 9.6427892591136599e-001 3.5721074088633946e-002
 1.8799999999999999e+000 9.6483236052650689e-001 3.5167639473493086e-002
 1.8900000000000001e+000 9.6537272951617370e-001 3.4627270483826279e-002
 1.8999999999999999e+000 9.6590045029666316e-001 3.4099549703336847e-002
 1.9100000000000001e+000 9.6641592338703142e-001 3.3584076612968486e-002
 1.9199999999999999e+000 9.6691953323989288e-001 3.3080466760107140e-002
 1.9300000000000002e+000 9.6741164902405941e-001 3.2588350975940525e-002
 1.9399999999999999e+000 9.6789262536224308e-001 3.2107374637756883e-002
 1.9500000000000002e+000 9.6836280302679123e-001 3.1637196973208645e-002
 1.9600000000000000e+000 9.6882250959621130e-001 3.1177490403788699e-002
 1.9700000000000000e+000 9.6927206007502731e-001 3.0727939924972785e-002
 1.9800000000000000e+000 9.6971175747933225e-001 3.0288242520667634e-002
 1.9900000000000000e+000 9.7014189339022228e-001 2.9858106609777578e-002
 2.0000000000000000e+000 9.7056274847714075e-001 2.9437251522859406e-002
 2.0099999999999998e+000 9.7097459299301891e-001 2.9025407006981151e-002
 2.0200000000000000e+000 9.7137768724296569e-001 2.8622312757034214e-002
 2.0300000000000002e+000 9.7177228202812926e-001 2.8227717971870896e-002
 2.0400000000000000e+000 9.7215861906624745e-001 2.7841380933752619e-002
 2.0499999999999998e+000 9.7253693139030017e-001 2.7463068609699801e-002
 2.0600000000000001e+000 9.7290744372657045e-001 2.7092556273429484e-002
 2.0700000000000003e+000 9.7327037285334328e-001 2.6729627146656873e-002
 2.0800000000000001e+000 9.7362592794138070e-001 2.6374072058619209e-002
 2.0899999999999999e+000 9.7397431087724418e-001 2.6025689122755900e-002
 2.1000000000000001e+000 9.7431571657044924e-001 2.5684283429550554e-002
 2.1100000000000003e+000 9.7465033324539518e-001 2.5349666754604816e-002
 2.1200000000000001e+000 9.7497834271892503e-001 2.5021657281074725e-002
 2.1299999999999999e+000 9.7529992066434334e-001 2.4700079335656738e-002
 2.1400000000000001e+000 9.7561523686263774e-001 2.4384763137362177e-002
 2.1500000000000004e+000 9.7592445544163176e-001 2.4075544558368172e-002
 2.1600000000000001e+000 9.7622773510372407e-001 2.3772264896276020e-002
 2.1699999999999999e+000 9.7652522934284780e-001 2.3474770657152248e-002
 2.1799999999999997e+000 9.7681708665123512e-001 2.3182913348764919e-002
 2.1899999999999999e+000 9.7710345071653604e-001 2.2896549283463852e-002
 2.2000000000000002e+000 9.7738446060981210e-001 2.2615539390187827e-002
 2.2100000000000000e+000 9.7766025096488718e-001 2.2339749035112880e-002
 2.2199999999999998e+000 9.7793095214951498e-001 2.2069047850485014e-002
 2.2300000000000000e+000 9.7819669042879254e-001 2.1803309571207529e-002
 2.2400000000000002e+000 9.7845758812121986e-001 2.1542411878780129e-002
 2.2500000000000000e+000 9.7871376374779184e-001 2.1286236252208168e-002
 2.2599999999999998e+000 9.7896533217447401e-001 2.1034667825525849e-002
 2.2700000000000000e+000 9.7921240474840532e-001 2.0787595251594650e-002
 2.2800000000000002e+000 9.7945508942813952e-001 2.0544910571860531e-002
 2.2900000000000000e+000 9.7969349090823021e-001 2.0306509091769800e-002
 2.2999999999999998e+000 9.7992771073843910e-001 2.0072289261561006e-002
 2.3100000000000001e+000 9.8015784743783319e-001 1.9842152562166804e-002
 2.3200000000000003e+000 9.8038399660402631e-001 1.9616003395973816e-002
 2.3300000000000001e+000 9.8060625101779697e-001 1.9393748982202936e-002
 2.3399999999999999e+000 9.8082470074331440e-001 1.9175299256685558e-002
 2.3500000000000001e+000 9.8103943322417630e-001 1.8960566775823733e-002
 2.3600000000000003e+000 9.8125053337546664e-001 1.8749466624533376e-002
 2.3700000000000001e+000 9.8145808367201903e-001 1.8541916327981144e-002
 2.3799999999999999e+000 9.8166216423306485e-001 1.8337835766935082e-002
 2.3900000000000001e+000 9.8186285290344055e-001 1.8137147096559478e-002
 2.4000000000000004e+000 9.8206022533150705e-001 1.7939774668492756e-002
 2.4100000000000001e+000 9.8225435504394387e-001 1.7745644956056211e-002
 2.4199999999999999e+000 9.8244531351755093e-001 1.7554686482448935e-002
 2.4299999999999997e+000 9.8263317024820784e-001 1.7366829751792216e-002
 2.4399999999999999e+000 9.8281799281710636e-001 1.7182007182893717e-002
 2.4500000000000002e+000 9.8299984695439213e-001 1.7000153045607983e-002
 2.4600000000000000e+000 9.8317879660032348e-001 1.6821203399676670e-002
 2.4699999999999998e+000 9.8335490396406244e-001 1.6645096035937553e-002
 2.4800000000000000e+000 9.8352822958020303e-001 1.6471770419797045e-002
 2.4900000000000002e+000 9.8369883236313393e-001 1.6301167636866145e-002
 2.5000000000000000e+000 9.8386676965933506e-001 1.6133230340664932e-002
 2.5099999999999998e+000 9.8403209729769492e-001 1.5967902702305026e-002
 2.5200000000000000e+000 9.8419486963793534e-001 1.5805130362064556e-002
 2.5300000000000002e+000 9.8435513961722654e-001 1.5644860382773552e-002
 2.5400000000000000e+000 9.8451295879506762e-001 1.5487041204932404e-002
 2.5499999999999998e+000 9.8466837739651070e-001 1.5331622603489520e-002
 2.5600000000000001e+000 9.8482144435379271e-001 1.5178555646207220e-002
 2.5700000000000003e+000 9.8497220734645030e-001 1.5027792653549926e-002
 2.5800000000000001e+000 9.8512071283996994e-001 1.4879287160029836e-002
 2.5899999999999999e+000 9.8526700612305040e-001 1.4732993876949915e-002
 2.6000000000000001e+000 9.8541113134351410e-001 1.4588868656485954e-002
 2.6100000000000003e+000 9.8555313154294699e-001 1.4446868457052868e-002
 2.6200000000000001e+000 9.8569304869009788e-001 1.4306951309902158e-002
 2.6299999999999999e+000 9.8583092371309955e-001 1.4169076286900549e-002
 2.6400000000000001e+000 9.8596679653055785e-001 1.4033203469441889e-002
 2.6500000000000004e+000 9.8610070608155342e-001 1.3899293918446800e-002
 2.6600000000000001e+000 9.8623269035459404e-001 1.3767309645405793e-002
 2.6699999999999999e+000 9.8636278641557495e-001 1.3637213584425201e-002
 2.6799999999999997e+000 9.8649103043476449e-001 1.3508969565235264e-002
 2.6899999999999999e+000 9.8661745771287723e-001 1.3382542287122769e-002
 2.7000000000000002e+000 9.8674210270624763e-001 1.3257897293752006e-002
 2.7100000000000000e+000 9.8686499905116076e-001 1.3135000948839140e-002
 2.7199999999999998e+000 9.8698617958735291e-001 1.3013820412646924e-002
 2.7300000000000000e+000 9.8710567638073177e-001 1.2894323619268120e-002
 2.7400000000000002e+000 9.8722352074533293e-001 1.2776479254667052e-002
 2.7500000000000000e+000 9.8733974326454921e-001 1.2660256735450733e-002
 2.7599999999999998e+000 9.8745437381165868e-001 1.2545626188341158e-002
 2.7700000000000000e+000 9.8756744156967713e-001 1.2432558430322852e-002
 2.7800000000000002e+000 9.8767897505056035e-001 1.2321024949439780e-002
 2.7900000000000000e+000 9.8778900211378229e-001 1.2210997886217517e-002
 2.7999999999999998e+000 9.8789754998431289e-001 1.2102450015687103e-002
 2.8100000000000001e+000 9.8800464527001153e-001 1.1995354729988609e-002
 2.8200000000000003e+000 9.8811031397846727e-001 1.1889686021532614e-002
 2.8300000000000001e+000 9.8821458153330077e-001 1.1785418466699435e-002
 2.8399999999999999e+000 9.8831747278994397e-001 1.1682527210056040e-002
 2.8500000000000001e+000 9.8841901205092797e-001 1.1580987949072214e-002
 2.8600000000000003e+000 9.8851922308068252e-001 1.1480776919317662e-002
 2.8700000000000001e+000 9.8861812911987734e-001 1.1381870880122671e-002
 2.8799999999999999e+000 9.8871575289931424e-001 1.1284247100685877e-002
 2.8900000000000001e+000 9.8881211665338697e-001 1.1187883346612935e-002
 2.9000000000000004e+000 9.8890724213312897e-001 1.1092757866871042e-002
 2.9100000000000001e+000 9.8900115061885563e-001 1.0998849381144411e-002
 2.9199999999999999e+000 9.8909386293242341e-001 1.0906137067576616e-002
 2.9299999999999997e+000 9.8918539944911388e-001 1.0814600550886217e-002
 2.9399999999999999e+000 9.8927578010915718e-001 1.0724219890842865e-002
 2.9500000000000002e+000 9.8936502442890895e-001 1.0634975571090985e-002
 2.9600000000000000e+000 9.8945315151169055e-001 1.0546848488309423e-002
 2.9699999999999998e+000 9.8954018005830502e-001 1.0459819941695108e-002
 2.9800000000000000e+000 9.8962612837724018e-001 1.0373871622759956e-002
 2.9900000000000002e+000 9.8971101439456965e-001 1.0288985605430241e-002
 3.0000000000000000e+000 9.8979485566356196e-001 1.0205144336438028e-002
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis} [
        xlabel = $E/U_0$,
        enlarge y limits=false,         % <---
        minor tick num=4,               % <---
        no marks,                       % <---
        every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick}
                    ]
           \addplot table [x index = 0, y index = 1]  {data.csv};
           \addplot table [x index = 0, y index = 2]  {data.csv};
           \legend{$T$, $R$};
       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

in the second case the code of diagrams is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis} [
        xlabel = $E/U_0$,
        enlarge y limits=false,         % <---
        minor tick num=4,               % <---
        no marks,                       % <---
        every axis plot post/.append style={ultra thick}
                    ]
           \addplot table [x index = 0, y index = 1]  {data.csv} node[below left] {$T$};
           \addplot table [x index = 0, y index = 2]  {data.csv} node[above left] {$R$};
       \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

note for your diagram it is sufficient to have determined only two decimal digits and far less points.